# Set IIS 10 server to public

Tags: windows, iis, ip, iis-10

I'm pretty new to fiddling with servers (have a background in programming, but not server management), so please bear with me if I ask basic questions and link through to any tutorials you think I should follow.

I'm trying to set up a public IIS 10 server from an AWS Windows VM. From the VM I can connect to the localhost, but from anywhere else the connection results in `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. I think it's because my server is set to localhost, but I can't find how I can make it public. Whenever I Google it I just get "how to make a local IIS server".

Here's what it currently looks like:
[image: image ss]

I got this result by following the official Windows tutorial for setting up an ASP.NET website with IIS Manager, [found here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). I'm hosting the site on port 6911 and I've opened that port on the Windows Firewall as well. Please ask for any additional clarification if necessary.

So basically my questions are:

- Will setting it from localhost to public (or the equivalent) work?
- If so, how do I do it?

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: I opened the Firewall port 6911 on the server, which is also used by IIS. Is there a way to check whether the port is actually available?

Comment: `1.` Why are you using port 6911? `2.` Have you configured your AWS security group for this VM to allow inbound traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft IIS does not have a concept of `localhost` vs. `public`.

In your screenshot you show IIS Manager running on a machine `EC2AMAZ-NN0LTIR` the term `localhost` next to it, just means that this IIS instance is local to `EC2AMAZ-NN0LTIR`, it is not a remote connection from this server to another one.

There is nothing inside IIS to make it public, that is the default and only mode it has.

To make it accessible from the outside world, you may have to open the Windows firewall and in your case any further AWS firewalls and configure their network connections.

So you need to concentrate your troubleshooting on firewalls and network connections not on IIS.